# Null and blank check of excel cell values and setting data not working in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading data from Excel using POI and Java.

My Java code:

```
public MyObject setMyData(MyObject myObject)(

    myObject.setLang(row.getCell(++cellInd).getStringCellValue()); 

    // like above many more values are set with different datatypes

}
```

This is throwing error while setting the value as the cell is null.

```
 public boolean checkNullBlankValueOfCell(Cell cell) {

    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```